# Setting Same-Site cookie attribute to Lax

Tags: cookies, csrf, same-site-cookies

Is setting `Same-Site` attribute of a cookie to `Lax` the same as not setting it at all? If there are differences what are they?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> Is setting Same-Site attribute of a cookie to lax the same as not setting the Same-Site attribute?

**In Google Chrome < 76 – no.** Setting `SameSite=lax` is safer than omitting the attribute. (But if your implementation currently relies on cross-origin requests, double-check that adding the attribute doesn't break anything.)

Here are the differences:

- When you don't set the `SameSite` attribute, the cookie is always sent.
- With `SameSite=lax`, the cookie is only sent on same-site requests or  top-level navigation with a safe HTTP method. That is, it will not be sent with cross-domain `POST` requests or when loading the site in a cross-origin frame, but it will be sent when you navigate to the site via a standard top-level `<a href=...>` link.
- With `SameSite=strict` (or an invalid value), the cookie is never sent in cross-site requests. Even when clicking a top-level link on a third-party domain to your site, the browser will refuse to send the cookie.

**Starting with Chrome 76**, your browser has an option to make no `SameSite` behave like `Samesite=Lax`. This will be **default in Chrome 80**. From the [feature](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592) description:

> The Stable version of Chrome 80 is targeted for enabling this feature
> by default. The feature will be enabled in the Beta version only,
> starting in Chrome 78. This feature is available as of Chrome 76 by
> enabling the same-site-by-default-cookies flag.

Also have a look at the [RFC draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-first-party-cookies-07) and Sjoerd's [blog post](https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2016/04/14/preventing-csrf-with-samesite-cookie-attribute/).

Comment: "currently limited" means limited to just chrome and clones... good answer btw.

Comment: Firefox supports SameSite since Firefox 60 and was released May 9, 2018

Comment: The 3rd bullet point doesn’t make sense to me. Are you saying if I click on a link from a third-party domain into my site that the first page load will not send my site’s  `SameSite=strict` cookies to my site’s server?

Comment: @MrColes Correct, do you find it confusingly phrased?

Comment: @Arminius ok, sounds like I understand it then, and I was maybe making bad assumptions as to how one would use each. Seems like if you had a session cookie on a site, then as long as you don’t want it inside an iframe from a 3rd party site it should be `SameSite=lax`, because you’d need it on first page loads. However, if you want a cookie to *only* be sent on additional requests that page makes (ajax, images, css, etc. if on same site) then it could be `SameSite=strict`?

Comment: @MrColes Exactly! Also note how enforcing `lax`/`strict` makes vulnerabilities like CSRF increasingly hard to exploit.

Answer (score 3):

This is currently changed in Chrome - and this means that not setting SameSite is actually considered LAX.

https://blog.chromium.org/2019/05/improving-privacy-and-security-on-web.html

Answer (score 1):

Chrome recently implemented the `SameSite=Lax` by default if `SameSite=None` is not explicitly specified.

Additionally, the `Secure` attribute MUST be set when specifying `SameSite=None`, if not Chrome will ignore it.

https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592